# Add groovy script to run through gradle android

Tags: java, android, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I want to run some groovy scripts before gradle builds debug apk in Android.

```
task batchTask(type: JavaExec) {
    description 'running tasks'
    exec {
        commandLine './Batch.groovy'
    }

}
```

added this to build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'groovyx.grooid.groovy-android'

android{
        ...

        dependsOn {
            batchTask
        }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.0:grooid'
}
```

added this to build.grade(android)

dependencies {
  ...
    classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.6'
}

I keep getting the error Error:Cause: error=13, Permission denied

stack trace

> 15:24:22.688 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle]
>   Changing state to: STARTING 15:24:22.689 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process
>   started: command './Batch.groovy'. 15:24:22.693 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to:
>   FAILED 15:24:22.693 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command
>   './Batch.groovy'' finished with exit value -1 (state: FAILED)
>   15:24:22.695 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing:
>   Running the build script took 1.866 secs 15:24:22.798 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  15:24:22.799 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an
>   exception. 15:24:22.799 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   15:24:22.800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went
>   wrong: 15:24:22.800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] A
>   problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. 15:24:22.800 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > A problem occurred starting
>   process 'command './Batch.groovy'' 15:24:22.801 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  15:24:22.801 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try: 15:24:22.801 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to
>   get the stack trace.  15:24:22.802 [LIFECYCLE]
>   [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]  15:24:22.802 [LIFECYCLE]
>   [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED

Update:

Running the task inside a Groovy shell did the trick.

```
task batchTask(type: JavaExec) {
    description 'batchTask in progress'

    new GroovyShell().run(file('Batch.groovy'))
}
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to run a command line `Exec` job with a `JavaExec` task?

Comment: Can you  upload screenshot of build.grade(android)  and build.gradle(app)?

Comment: gradlew assemleDebug  --stacktrace

Comment: @tinysunlight A screenshot?!?!?!

Comment: @tim_yates try@noisy ninja's.

Answer (score 0):

Running the task inside a Groovy shell did the trick.

```
task batchTask(type: JavaExec) {
    description 'batchTask in progress'

    new GroovyShell().run(file('Batch.groovy'))
}
```